# PHP prepared statements - check if a value already exists

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a check on a value (email), to determine if it already exist in the db. This should be done using prepared statements. What is the best way for doing this? My solution is this (which is wrong):

```
$mysqli = connectToDB();
$getEmail = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?') or die('Couldn\'t check the email');
$getEmail->bind_param('s', $email);
$getEmail->execute();
$countRows = $getEmail->num_rows;
print $countRows;
```

It always prints out 0 even though the email aready exists in the db.

Comment: Are you sure the email exists in the database in exactly the same upper/lower case?  Try using a case-insensitive comparison: `WHERE lcase(email)=lcase(?)`

Comment: Yes i am sure about that, both are lowercase. I tried your solution though. It didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have an issue regarding unbuffered result. You should use store_result:

```
$getEmail->execute();
$getEmail->store_result();
$countRows = $getEmail->num_rows;
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my issue too :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `$getEmail->store_result();`

```
$mysqli = connectToDB();
$getEmail = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');
$getEmail->bind_param('s', $email);
$getEmail->execute();
$getEmail->store_result();
$countRows = $getEmail->num_rows;
print $countRows;
```